# Convert dataframe row in R to date

Tags: r, date, dataframe

Is there an easy way to change a row (instead of a column) into the date class within a larger data frame?

All I would like to do is have the first row of a data frame be dates (specifically, month-ends) that are relevant to all of the data in each column. However, when I transpose the dates as a workaround (first convert to date in column form, then transpose to row and switch to dataframe) the dates convert back to factors (seen below).

```
datetemp$monthdate <- as.Date(datetemp$Month, '%m/%d/%Y')
monthdates <- as.data.frame(t(datetemp))
monthrow <- monthdates[-1, ] #to delete first row and leave a 1x121 df
row.names(monthrow) <- NULL
class(monthrow[1, 2]) #this is factor, not date as desired
```

I also tried to just keep the list of dates in a date format (where daterow3 below is Date[121] format). But when I try to bind the date row to the dataframe later, it gives the error below, even though both the original and the date list have 121 columns.

```
datecol <- datetemp[, -1]
daterow2 <- t(datecol)
daterow3 <- unname(daterow2)
# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
# numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Please share, if possible, a sensible workaround that would allow me to have dates in the first row of a df instead of in the first column. Thank you for your help.

***Edit: As requested, the datetemp object below:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(121L, 1L, 41L, 51L, 61L, 71L, 
81L, 91L, 101L, 111L, 11L, 21L, 31L, 2L, 42L, 52L, 62L, 72L, 
82L, 92L, 102L, 112L, 12L, 22L, 32L, 3L, 43L, 53L, 63L, 73L, 
83L, 93L, 103L, 113L, 13L, 23L, 33L, 4L, 49L, 54L, 64L, 74L, 
84L, 94L, 104L, 114L, 14L, 24L, 34L, 5L, 44L, 55L, 65L, 75L, 
85L, 95L, 105L, 115L, 15L, 25L, 35L, 6L, 45L, 56L, 66L, 76L, 
86L, 96L, 106L, 116L, 16L, 26L, 36L, 7L, 46L, 57L, 67L, 77L, 
87L, 97L, 107L, 117L, 17L, 27L, 37L, 8L, 50L, 58L, 68L, 78L, 
88L, 98L, 108L, 118L, 18L, 28L, 38L, 9L, 47L, 59L, 69L, 79L, 
89L, 99L, 109L, 119L, 19L, 29L, 39L, 10L, 48L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 
90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 20L, 30L, 40L), .Names = c("CUSIP", "X12.31.2004.1.31.2005", 
"X1.31.2005.2.28.2005", "X2.28.2005.3.31.2005", "X3.31.2005.4.29.2005", 
"X4.29.2005.5.31.2005", "X5.31.2005.6.30.2005", "X6.30.2005.7.29.2005", 
"X7.29.2005.8.31.2005", "X8.31.2005.9.30.2005", "X9.30.2005.10.31.2005", 
"X10.31.2005.11.30.2005", "X11.30.2005.12.30.2005", "X12.30.2005.1.31.2006", 
"X1.31.2006.2.28.2006", "X2.28.2006.3.31.2006", "X3.31.2006.4.28.2006", 
"X4.28.2006.5.31.2006", "X5.31.2006.6.30.2006", "X6.30.2006.7.31.2006", 
"X7.31.2006.8.31.2006", "X8.31.2006.9.29.2006", "X9.29.2006.10.31.2006", 
"X10.31.2006.11.30.2006", "X11.30.2006.12.29.2006", "X12.29.2006.1.31.2007", 
"X1.31.2007.2.28.2007", "X2.28.2007.3.30.2007", "X3.30.2007.4.30.2007", 
"X4.30.2007.5.31.2007", "X5.31.2007.6.29.2007", "X6.29.2007.7.31.2007", 
"X7.31.2007.8.31.2007", "X8.31.2007.9.28.2007", "X9.28.2007.10.31.2007", 
"X10.31.2007.11.30.2007", "X11.30.2007.12.31.2007", "X12.31.2007.1.31.2008", 
"X1.31.2008.2.29.2008", "X2.29.2008.3.31.2008", "X3.31.2008.4.30.2008", 
"X4.30.2008.5.30.2008", "X5.30.2008.6.30.2008", "X6.30.2008.7.31.2008", 
"X7.31.2008.8.29.2008", "X8.29.2008.9.30.2008", "X9.30.2008.10.31.2008", 
"X10.31.2008.11.28.2008", "X11.28.2008.12.31.2008", "X12.31.2008.1.30.2009", 
"X1.30.2009.2.27.2009", "X2.27.2009.3.31.2009", "X3.31.2009.4.30.2009", 
"X4.30.2009.5.29.2009", "X5.29.2009.6.30.2009", "X6.30.2009.7.31.2009", 
"X7.31.2009.8.31.2009", "X8.31.2009.9.30.2009", "X9.30.2009.10.30.2009", 
"X10.30.2009.11.30.2009", "X11.30.2009.12.31.2009", "X12.31.2009.1.29.2010", 
"X1.29.2010.2.26.2010", "X2.26.2010.3.31.2010", "X3.31.2010.4.30.2010", 
"X4.30.2010.5.31.2010", "X5.31.2010.6.30.2010", "X6.30.2010.7.30.2010", 
"X7.30.2010.8.31.2010", "X8.31.2010.9.30.2010", "X9.30.2010.10.29.2010", 
"X10.29.2010.11.30.2010", "X11.30.2010.12.31.2010", "X12.31.2010.1.31.2011", 
"X1.31.2011.2.28.2011", "X2.28.2011.3.31.2011", "X3.31.2011.4.29.2011", 
"X4.29.2011.5.31.2011", "X5.31.2011.6.30.2011", "X6.30.2011.7.29.2011", 
"X7.29.2011.8.31.2011", "X8.31.2011.9.30.2011", "X9.30.2011.10.31.2011", 
"X10.31.2011.11.30.2011", "X11.30.2011.12.30.2011", "X12.30.2011.1.31.2012", 
"X1.31.2012.2.29.2012", "X2.29.2012.3.30.2012", "X3.30.2012.4.30.2012", 
"X4.30.2012.5.31.2012", "X5.31.2012.6.29.2012", "X6.29.2012.7.31.2012", 
"X7.31.2012.8.31.2012", "X8.31.2012.9.28.2012", "X9.28.2012.10.31.2012", 
"X10.31.2012.11.30.2012", "X11.30.2012.12.31.2012", "X12.31.2012.1.31.2013", 
"X1.31.2013.2.28.2013", "X2.28.2013.3.29.2013", "X3.29.2013.4.30.2013", 
"X4.30.2013.5.31.2013", "X5.31.2013.6.28.2013", "X6.28.2013.7.31.2013", 
"X7.31.2013.8.30.2013", "X8.30.2013.9.30.2013", "X9.30.2013.10.31.2013", 
"X10.31.2013.11.29.2013", "X11.29.2013.12.31.2013", "X12.31.2013.1.31.2014", 
"X1.31.2014.2.28.2014", "X2.28.2014.3.31.2014", "X3.31.2014.4.30.2014", 
"X4.30.2014.5.30.2014", "X5.30.2014.6.30.2014", "X6.30.2014.7.31.2014", 
"X7.31.2014.8.29.2014", "X8.29.2014.9.30.2014", "X9.30.2014.10.31.2014", 
"X10.31.2014.11.28.2014", "X11.28.2014.12.31.2014"), .Label = c("1/31/2005", 
"1/31/2006", "1/31/2007", "1/31/2008", "1/31/2009", "1/31/2010", 
"1/31/2011", "1/31/2012", "1/31/2013", "1/31/2014", "10/31/2005", 
"10/31/2006", "10/31/2007", "10/31/2008", "10/31/2009", "10/31/2010", 
"10/31/2011", "10/31/2012", "10/31/2013", "10/31/2014", "11/30/2005", 
"11/30/2006", "11/30/2007", "11/30/2008", "11/30/2009", "11/30/2010", 
"11/30/2011", "11/30/2012", "11/30/2013", "11/30/2014", "12/31/2005", 
"12/31/2006", "12/31/2007", "12/31/2008", "12/31/2009", "12/31/2010", 
"12/31/2011", "12/31/2012", "12/31/2013", "12/31/2014", "2/28/2005", 
"2/28/2006", "2/28/2007", "2/28/2009", "2/28/2010", "2/28/2011", 
"2/28/2013", "2/28/2014", "2/29/2008", "2/29/2012", "3/31/2005", 
"3/31/2006", "3/31/2007", "3/31/2008", "3/31/2009", "3/31/2010", 
"3/31/2011", "3/31/2012", "3/31/2013", "3/31/2014", "4/30/2005", 
"4/30/2006", "4/30/2007", "4/30/2008", "4/30/2009", "4/30/2010", 
"4/30/2011", "4/30/2012", "4/30/2013", "4/30/2014", "5/31/2005", 
"5/31/2006", "5/31/2007", "5/31/2008", "5/31/2009", "5/31/2010", 
"5/31/2011", "5/31/2012", "5/31/2013", "5/31/2014", "6/30/2005", 
"6/30/2006", "6/30/2007", "6/30/2008", "6/30/2009", "6/30/2010", 
"6/30/2011", "6/30/2012", "6/30/2013", "6/30/2014", "7/31/2005", 
"7/31/2006", "7/31/2007", "7/31/2008", "7/31/2009", "7/31/2010", 
"7/31/2011", "7/31/2012", "7/31/2013", "7/31/2014", "8/31/2005", 
"8/31/2006", "8/31/2007", "8/31/2008", "8/31/2009", "8/31/2010", 
"8/31/2011", "8/31/2012", "8/31/2013", "8/31/2014", "9/30/2005", 
"9/30/2006", "9/30/2007", "9/30/2008", "9/30/2009", "9/30/2010", 
"9/30/2011", "9/30/2012", "9/30/2013", "9/30/2014", "Month"), class = "factor"), 
    monthdate = structure(c(NA, 12814, 12842, 12873, 12903, 12934, 
    12964, 12995, 13026, 13056, 13087, 13117, 13148, 13179, 13207, 
    13238, 13268, 13299, 13329, 13360, 13391, 13421, 13452, 13482, 
    13513, 13544, 13572, 13603, 13633, 13664, 13694, 13725, 13756, 
    13786, 13817, 13847, 13878, 13909, 13938, 13969, 13999, 14030, 
    14060, 14091, 14122, 14152, 14183, 14213, 14244, 14275, 14303, 
    14334, 14364, 14395, 14425, 14456, 14487, 14517, 14548, 14578, 
    14609, 14640, 14668, 14699, 14729, 14760, 14790, 14821, 14852, 
    14882, 14913, 14943, 14974, 15005, 15033, 15064, 15094, 15125, 
    15155, 15186, 15217, 15247, 15278, 15308, 15339, 15370, 15399, 
    15430, 15460, 15491, 15521, 15552, 15583, 15613, 15644, 15674, 
    15705, 15736, 15764, 15795, 15825, 15856, 15886, 15917, 15948, 
    15978, 16009, 16039, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 16221, 
    16251, 16282, 16313, 16343, 16374, 16404, 16435), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Month", 
"monthdate"), row.names = c(NA, -121L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please include the `datetemp` object in your question (`dput(datetemp)`)

Comment: No.  Don't do this.  Columns are type specific.  Rows are not.  You'll be opening up a can of worms by changing a whole row to the same class across all columns

Comment: Not really. The point of a data.frame (what distinguishes it from a matrix) is that the columns can have different classes, but each column is of one class.

Comment: Okay. The reason I'd like to do this is because it's a df with a cross-sectional sample. Each row is a different thing, and each column is ideally a different month. Would you recommend melting the data instead?

Comment: I'd recommend you look into the `dplyr` package for this type of grouped analysis.  They made it pretty easy on the user.  Or you could make each column **name** the name of the month, since they are all different you say.

Comment: You could convert your date into a string variable before transposing it. But having the date in the 1st row might not be the best option if you have columns with different types of data (eg. string, numeric, factors) across columns. Either the date or the rest of the columns will have to be coerced to a unique class. Depending on your goals, you might want to explore other solutions (not working with a dataframe or bringing the date information in at a later stage of your code).

Comment: Okay thank you all. To Richard, I also explored that but do not know how to maintain date format within the column names. I need to match by date in a later step in the process, which is why I am so eager to maintain date formats.

Comment: If you can't name your columns with the name of the month as suggested above, you could transpose your data and switch from a wide format to a long one. That way all your dates would be contained in a column.

Comment: You should post the first few rows of the original data in the text file. You have used read.table on a text file and read in the column headers as the first row of data.